# Set app icon badge number on notification while app is not runnin with expo managed

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, expo

I am having some issues displaying the number of notifications on badges on Android while using expo managed workflow.

I want the badge to update when the app is killed.
On IOS is working fine by setting the badge variable a number but somehow on android i only get a little dot that is telling me that there are unread notifications but no badge is shown.

This is how it should display:
[image]

But i am getting only a dot on the icon like on this example:
[image]

My question is that by using the badge variable should while sending out push messages from the backend should this be working on android aswell and i am messing something up or do i need another approche on android?

Any suggestions are welcome since i cant find any answer on this and been searching for days now.

Many thanks,
Trix

Comment: What library are you using for the notifications?

Comment: in the app "expo-notifications": "~0.11.6", on the backend i built a function that interacts with the expo notification servers using their API

Comment: I have the same issue. did you figure out why?

Answer (score 0):

Android notifications icon works different than on iOS because these are just one color, with transparency.
So when you reference the icon image make sure it has the transparency, if not, all the form is filled.

Also check your app.json to add this:

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/#custom-notification-icon-and-colors-android-only

https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#notification

Comment: Hey zelda11! Thank you for trying to help out, however i think you misunderstood my issue or its only me that i can't find the correlation between the two. My notification icon displays correctly. The problem is with the badge that should appear on the app icon in your app list displaying how many unread notifications you have. Thats the only that is not showing up on android. I have updated my question with photos.

Comment: ahh ok! Yes I misunderstood. Are you sure that Android supports that kind of possibility?
Seems that not by default, I've found this:
https://forums.expo.dev/t/how-can-i-show-badge-number-on-android-app/30833/2
https://www.samsung.com/hk_en/support/mobile-devices/android-o-os-app-icon-can-show-badges-with-numbers-or-dot-style-badges/